# Are there good WPF control libraries out there?

Tags: wpf, controls

Do you know any good WPF control library (even commercial) and what experiences have you made with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) has a commercial line of WPF controls, as well as WinForms, and Silverlight.  They are very high quality, and on the high end in terms of $$$, but they're worth their weight in gold if you're going to utilize them.

I've used their web products and they are well made.  They even have sample code on their site and demos so you can get started easily.

Comment: Bear in mind however, that if your product needs customized tool bars, Telerik does not support this.

Answer (score 1):

[Odyssey](http://www.codeplex.com/odyssey) is a nice set of controls with a Ribbon menu control and Outlook-style bars.

*You may have problems using them in XBAP applications though.*

Answer (score 1):

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) have a rich set as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview) has some excellent WPF and WinForm controls (commercial).  I'll admit I have only used their WinForm controls, but if their WPF controls are anything similar, they will be great.