# WPF chart controls in MVVM

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I Am trying to create a chart control dynamically. i am using WPF Toolkit chart controls.

Is this the best one when we think in terms of OpenSource and MVVM binding ? I donot see that it supports 3d charts.

I saw some sampl how we can bind the chart to View model. But i want my app to be dynamic. What my requirement is that, the settings will be stored in database . these setting include all chart details such as Series type, series data , X-axis data and everything. The app should be able to build the chart on fly reading the metadata. It should be able to create Multiple types of series (For example: a chart : one series : Line and another as column)

I saw a sample, but that doensot say me how to bind the series collection of a chart.

Anyone who has tried this or any suggestion ?

- Girija

Comment: Why not store the settings in the 'database' that is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the best one when we think in terms of OpenSource and MVVM binding ?

I'm not a big fan of WPF Toolkit controls.

I've written and tested apps that used them in the past, and they were flaky, and weren't very well designed.

In particular, the `DataGrid` was flaky.  It was often the cause of exceptions and accessibility problems.

The `AutoCompleteBox` wasn't well designed.  It tries to be extensible, but doesn't do a very good job of it.  It didn't work very cleanly for use as a directory auto-complete box (due to issues with updating the auto-complete data source).

They also haven't been updated in nearly two years, yet have numerous reported bugs, which says to me that they've been abandoned. The Chart control you ask about is in of "preview" quality, not "stable", which is worse still.

Here are some places you could look for alternatives:

- [Are there good WPF control libraries out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915586) - I think all the ones linked are commercial
- http://wpftutorial.net/3rdPartyLibs.html - some off this link aren't commercial, and this is a much bigger list

The second link refers to a "Free 3D chart" on CodeProject.  Can't recommend for or against it, I just wanted to point it out.